# Error: "userResolver" defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a problem with resolvers in graphQL and get this error:

> Error: "userResolver" defined in resolvers, but not in schema

However, I can not find the mistake. I have already searched on Google, but so far found no solution.

My gist:
https://gist.github.com/peterklein/b063ee66871917cac120ae2ae263d002

Could someone get me on the right track?

Comment: If ApolloServer expects `resolvers` to be an object, what is each property on that object supposed to be? Does the `resolvers` object you're importing in `server.js` conform to that?

Answer (score 0):

From this [Modularizing resolvers docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/05d537071b78ec9b8691edf01f0ed2fd44a3b8eb/docs/source/data/data.md#modularizing-resolvers)

> We can accomplish the same modularity with resolvers by passing around multiple resolver objects and combining them together with Lodash's merge or other equivalent

You need to merge your `userResolver` and `taskResolver`.

E.g.

`server.js`:

```js
const { merge } = require('lodash');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
const typeDefs = require('./typeDefs');

// ...
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers: merge(resolvers.taskResolver, resolvers.userResolver),
});
// ...
```

Now, the apollo server works fine.

```sh
$ node server.js
Server listen on port: 3000
```